# Hiw to prove that additive inverse is not equal to multiplicative inverse?

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

Consider the rational number field. Then prove that additive inverse can not be equal multiplicative inverse.

It is easy to prove that the identity elements are different by the following reasoning.

Say if $0=1$

$a=a*1=a*0=0$ hence $a=0=1$  So the set contains exactly one element.

But how can I prove the same for inverse elements ?

In case of duplicate,please give the link of similar posts.

Comment: There are positive and negative numbers. The multiplicative inverse has the same sign, while the additive inverse has the opposite sign, so they must be different. In general fields, they may not be different. For example in the field $\mathbb{F}_{17}=\mathbb{Z}/17\mathbb{Z}$, the element $4$ has the same other element (namely $13$) as multiplicative inverse and additive inverse.

Comment: Can you provide a formal proof ?

Comment: How formal must I be? Can I ask what the formal definition of the rational number field is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $a\ne 0$ the multiplicative inverse is $1/a$

$$a+1/a=0$$ does not have a real solution.

Thus the multiplicative inverse of a real number is different from its additive inverse.

For complex numbers $i$ and $-i$ two inverses are the same.

$$i+(-i)=0$$ and $$i(-i)=1$$